# Validate HTTP request came from tap on NFC tag

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, nfc

A typical scenario encodes a tag with a URL. Tapping the tag makes an HTTP request which is resolved by the web server. Can I (we) determine the tap actually came from tapping the tag rather than requesting the URL using a bookmark or typing the URL into the address bar of a browser?

In the context of my question I need to learn how the mobile devices know what to do with the tap, i.e. what is the mechanism which makes the HTTP request?

In the context of my questions I need to learn if there is a way to do validation in this context knowing that HTTP_REFERER requires a click event to populate the variable with data. Is the tap a click event? Is the tap event driven?

I have C# and client-side scripting skills and will be hosting the URLs on a Windows server using nopCommerce developed with C# using MVC and the tags will of course be just about anywhere but I need to learn if there is a way to validate the tag was actually tapped to issue the HTTP request.

Comment: I doubt you can determine if the request comes from a tap on a device, the nearest you will get is through the referer and the user-agent, with them you can see the originating page and if the client comes from a mobile device.

Answer (score 2):

Now the question is a bit unclear but if I understand correctly you would like to determine if the person accesses the site by the use of NFC tag or by other means.

The simple answer is no, first off NFC tags dont open web pages. The software that reads the NFC tag will identify a `URI` tag type and may open the web page. For that simple reason it is the Software you are trying to detect not the tag itself. Therefore it will be impossible for you to definitivly say that *"Yes this is a NFC Tag"*.

However if you consider your issue. You need to know if the request has come from an NFC tag. Well why dont we simplify this, why not make your url specific for NFC

For example lets say you wish to access the product `MyCoolProdct` found at `http://www.example.com/mycoolproduct`. Sending the person to this URL directly will make it hard to identify that this is a NFC tag. But what if you changed the URL that was specific to NFC tags this could be by adding a query string paramter maybe.

`http://www.example.com/mycoolproduct?a=NFC`

Or you could make a rediection system so the end result is back to `/mycoolproduct` such as.

User accesses:
`http://www.example.com/nfctap?q=mycoolproduct`

NFC Tap action logs the request (session, user persistent store, [customer attributes]). Then redirects the user to the `q` url.

These are some of the basic ideas, however I think you are looking in the wrong place. It will be almost impossible to (and hard to maintain) accuratly detect NFC tags.

Comment: I'm using QueryStrings Nico and that entire URL gets encoded into the tag for example...

http://www.example.com/mycoolproduct?id=1234

However bookmarking saves the entire URL including the QueryString so using the value of the QueryString id on the server does nothing to help validate that the HTTP request for that URL was not loaded from a bookmark or typing the URL into the browser's address bar.

So far this implies NFC tags are virtually useless for a business model that requires validation in this context when each tap needs to be recorded as an actual tap on the tag.

Comment: If you would like to record the "TAPS" as individual units you will need to provide the NFC reading software, this is the only place you can guarentee accurate records. Anything outside of this can be altered or changed. Now to limit the browser bookmarks, if you detect `?id=xxx` I would suggest you log the tap, then redirect to the page without the `id` query string segment. Therefore browsers wont bookmark the page that records the tap.

Comment: I've determined a URL with a QueryString modified as a short link defeats bookmarking the tap; reloading any page the shortened link may be used to load is not a consideration as the objective is validating the tap as a tap.

On the other hand an NDEF reader can read a shortened URL encoded on the tag, copied and submitted manually time and time again which would skew the tap count.